# how do I input custom arrays into rows & columns in 2d character array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

```
Rows = int(input("give the number of rows:"))
Columns = int(input("Give the number of columns:"))
matrix = []

for i in range(Rows):
        matrix.append(['a', 'b', 'c','d', 'e'])
        
    for vector in matrix:
        print(matrix)
```

here's the output:

```
give the number of rows:3
Give the number of columns:3
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
```

[it needed to be like this when the user input the rows and columns 3x3]

### a  b  c

### d  e f

### g  h  i

Comment: What is the expected output? Are you expecting a 3 item array in which the items are vectors of length 3?

Comment: Your code's indentation makes it invalid.

Comment: i'm sorry. I'm really new to this.

Comment: Not a problem! There has been a submission posted below that seemingly solves your problem.

Comment: i finally finished the needed expected output. im sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to initalize an array with a specific size. Below is one of the more concise ways.

```
Rows = int(input("Give the number of rows:"))
Columns = int(input("Give the number of columns:"))
matrix = [["a"]*Rows]*Columns

print(matrix)
```

This will give the output

```
Give the number of rows:3
Give the number of columns:3
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
```

This gives the array sizing that you are looking for.

Comment: i've already edited the expected output i'm looking for. still gonna figure it out. thanks for the help anyway.